# Why is the stdlib implementation for primes so slow?

Tags: ruby, math, primes

I decided to code the sieve of eratosthenes in ruby for fun.  Only for fun because I knew there was a library function.  Also, I thought it would be fast. But I found that it is not, at least in my ruby 1.9.3,  mine is several times faster on my netbook and it's not even in c.  why is that so.

library implementation:

```
require 'prime'
primes = Prime.each(1_000_000).to_a
print primes.size
puts
```

mine in ruby:

```
sieve = Array.new(1_000_000, true)
sieve[0..1] = [false, false]
for number in 2...Math.sqrt(sieve.size)
  if sieve[number]
    for multiple in (number ** 2...sieve.size).step(number)
      sieve[multiple] = false
    end
  end
end

primes = []
for number in 2...1_000_000
  if sieve[number]
    primes << number
  end
end
print primes.size
puts
```

The library is very slow.

Comment: i think its time for me to upgrade to 2.2

Comment: If you want to get still a little faster use a number wheel as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892313/sieve-of-eratosthenes-with-wheel-factorization.

Answer (score 2):

The `prime` library `Prime.each(1_000_000).to_a` generates all prime numbers below `1_000_000`.

Your method actually only generate all prime number below the square root of `1_000_000`, i.e, `1000`.

Comment: yes, thanks for catching that. i updated it. but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

a) On my computer, library executes in 0.230s, your implementation in 0.270s on the average. EDIT: I executed on MRI 2.2.0 though, not 1.9.3.

b) More importantly, the library implementation for MRI is also [in Ruby](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/prime.rb), not in C. Not all functions in Ruby library are written in native code.

Comment: what version of ruby you are using?